# Find Least Squares Regression Line

Tags: statistics, convex-optimization, matlab, least-squares, linear-regression

I have a problem where I need to find the least squares regression line. I have found $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ in the following equation

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot x + \epsilon$$

So I have both the vectors $y$ and $x$.

I know that $\hat{y}$ the vector predictor of $y$ is $x \cdot \beta$ and that the residual vector is $\epsilon = y - \hat{y}$.

I know also that the least squares regression line looks something like this $$\hat{y} = a + b \cdot x$$
and that what I need to find is $a$ and $b$, but I don't know exactly how to do it. Currently I am using Matlab, and I need to do it in Matlab. Any idea how should I proceed, based on the fact that I am using Matlab?

Correct me if I did/said something wrong anyway.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with Matlab. However, do you know the formulas for the least-squares estimates of $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define

```
X = [ones(size(x)) x];
```

then type

```
regress(y,X)
```

---

Observations:

- the first step is to include a constant in the regression (otherwise you would be imposing $a=0$).
- the output will be a vector with the OLS estimates $(a,b)$.

Comment: @nbro That will achieve the same goal.

Comment: @nbro Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @nbro Yes, you would.

Comment: @nbro Yes, that should work.

Comment: @nbro As far as I can tell this should work...

Comment: @nbro, I don't understand your question. Without $a$ and $b$, how would you get $\hat y$?

Comment: @nbro I think you are getting confused by the notation. I'm not sure what is done in your note or book, bu it is usual to refer to the unknown population parameters by $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ as you have it in your first equation. Then, $a$ and $b$ denote the respective least squares estimates for those parameters. $X \beta$ is the same thing where $X=[ones,x]$ and $\beta = [\beta_0,\beta_1]$.

Comment: @nbro $X\beta = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x$.

Answer (score 1):

Sequence of $m$ measurements:
$$\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}$$
Model:
$$
 y(x) = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1} x
$$
Linear system:
$$
\begin{align}
%
\mathbf{A} \, \beta &= y \\
% A
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  1 & x_{1} \\
  1 & x_{2} \\
  \vdots & \vdots \\
  1 & x_{m}
\end{array} \right]
% beta
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \beta_{1} \\
  \beta_{2} 
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  y_{1} \\
  y_{2} \\
  \vdots \\
  y_{m}
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
Least squares solution:
$$
 \beta_{LS} = \left\{
  \beta \in \mathbb{C}^{2} \colon
\lVert
 \mathbf{A} \,x - y
\rVert_{2}^{2}
\text{ is minimized}
\right\}
$$
Solution type: we have full column rank. Solution is unique - a point.

---

Solution method 1: Normal equations
$$
\begin{align}
%
\mathbf{A}^{*} \,\mathbf{A} \, \beta &= \mathbf{A}^{*} \,y \\
% A
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{1} \cdot x \\
   x \cdot \mathbf{1} & x \cdot x 
\end{array} \right]
% beta
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \beta_{1} \\
  \beta_{2} 
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  \mathbf{1} \cdot y  \\
  x \cdot y
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
\begin{align}
%
\beta &= \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \, \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*} \,y \\
% beta
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
  \beta_{1} \\
  \beta_{2} 
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
% inv
\left( 
\left( \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{1} \right) 
\left( x \cdot x  \right)
-
\left( \mathbf{1} \cdot x \right)^{2}
\right)^{-1}
\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
   x \cdot x & -\mathbf{1} \cdot x \\
   -\mathbf{1} \cdot x & \mathbf{1} \cdot \mathbf{1} 
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  \mathbf{1} \cdot y  \\
  x \cdot y
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$

Solution method 2: Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse:
$$
\beta = \mathbf{A}^{+} y 
$$

---

The MATLAB intrinsic [mldivide](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) is one option.